# Flutter Firebase Delete Item from ListView.builder()

Tags: flutter, firebase, listview, stream

I'm trying to delete Items from my database in Firebase using the dismissible widget. I've read through multiple threads here on StackOverflow but none of the implementations work for me (always getting the error at the bottom). Can you help me and tell me what to change

```
class HomeScreenStreamBuilder extends StatelessWidget {
  const HomeScreenStreamBuilder({
    Key? key,
  }) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return StreamBuilder<QuerySnapshot>(
      stream: FirestoreMethods().readClipboardItems(),
      builder: ((context, AsyncSnapshot snapshot) {
        if (snapshot.hasData) {
          return ListView.builder(
            padding: const EdgeInsets.all(0),
            itemBuilder: ((context, index) {
              Map data = snapshot.data.docs[index].data();

              return Dismissible(
                  direction: DismissDirection.startToEnd,
                  onDismissed: (direction) {
                    FirestoreMethods()
                        .deleteClipboardItem(snapshot.data.docs.documentID);
                  },
                  key: ObjectKey(snapshot.data.docs.elementAt(index)),
                  child: ClipboardTile(text: data["text"]));
            }),
            itemCount: snapshot.data.docs.length,
          );
        } else {
          return Center(
            child: Text("Loading"),
          );
        }
      }),
    );
  }
}


FirebaseAPI:
  Stream<QuerySnapshot> readClipboardItems() {
    return FirebaseFirestore.instance
        .collection("users")
        .doc(_userUid)
        .collection("clipboardItems")
        .orderBy("created", descending: true)
        .snapshots();
  }
```

`Future deleteClipboardItem(String docId) async { return await FirebaseFirestore.instance .collection("users") .doc(_userUid) .collection("clipboardItems") .doc(docId) .delete() .then((doc) => print("document deleted"), onError: (e) => print("Error updating document $e")); }`

ERROR:
Class 'List<_JsonQueryDocumentSnapshot>' has no instance getter 'documentID'.
Receiver: Instance(length:16) of '_GrowableList'
Tried calling: documentID

Comment: Can you share your delete clipboardcarditem method code snippet.

Comment: You are trying to delete data of nested collection but something mentioned in firebase documents you can't delete sub collection like normal delete(). Check this link https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/manage-data/delete-data#collections. Check delete collections section.

Comment: @VishalZaveri Please check above. I put in the method.

Comment: First, you have to declare the return type with Future<datatype> for your method if you are returning anything from the method. i think you are not using that so you can write Future<void>.

Comment: Did you refer above comment link for delete sub-collection data?

Comment: @VishalZaveri correct. I have a collection named users which contains a list of user documents. Every user document contains another collection with clipboardItems. With my function I want to delete a single one of those clipboardItems.